# How do I read the state of a device driver in Windows?

Tags: windows

How do I read the state of a device driver? I know I can loop through drivers using EnumDeviceDrivers and reading their name with GetDeviceDriverFileName, but how do I find out if they are stopped, running, disabled etc?

DriverQuery.exe provides the info, but how do I read the info in my program without executing driverquery.exe ?

Comment: A driver is not a service.  It has no state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EnumDeviceDrivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Retrieves the load address for each device driver in the system.
i.e. It enums already loaded device drivers. What you need is to investigate Service Control Manager (SCM) api, as soon as one of the ways to load driver is assign it to SCM (in that case it driver DOES HAVE A STATE).

Check out this:
[EnumServicesStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682637%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)  (with dwServiceType = SERVICE_DRIVER)
[QueryServiceStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684939%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the hint, that helped! I found this article that shows how to use EnumServicesStatus - from there is is simple to get the state (running or not). http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=18601